# Fixing Chrome's content-disposition comma issue in IIS

Tags: google-chrome, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, http-headers

Chrome from version 16 became pretty strict on content-disposition headers having unquoted commas. While most sites out on the web will face user pressure to fix their servers this is not so easy for small or in-house intranet applications that no one is quite willing to touch.

[Thread on Chrome's forum about the issue, what works and what doesn't](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/H_DneQinvT0/discussion).

Short answer is that the `Content-Disposition` header, if included, needs to either not have commas in the filename or have filenames quoted.

We have one such system handling document management, **touching the codebase is NOT an option**, but any files with commas in their names will throw an error in Chrome. how can I fix this?

*Doing a bit of a [Jeopardy! thing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) here but not 100% confident on my answer and would appreciate comments/alternatives*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using IIS's URL Rewrite module which can also work on headers.

The key will be to match on `Content-Disposition` which includes filename= and doesn't have quotemarks for the filename.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Chrome Comma Fix">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern="^(.*)(filename=)(?!&quot;)([^&quot;]*)(;.*)?$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}&quot;{R:3}&quot;{R:4}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I haven't yet tested this though.

Comment: To those (like me) made a little nervous by the closing 'I haven't tested this yet', this works great.